# Get the second to last column per row that isn't null

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm trying to get the second to last non-null column per row, where the null could be in any column. Solutions such as this don't work due to where the null can be anywhere: [Pandas select the second to last column which is also not nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955900/pandas-select-the-second-to-last-column-which-is-also-not-nan)

**Not Ideal Solution:**
I was able to solve it with the following code, but there has to be a more concise way to write this. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
data = [[1, 10, np.nan, np.nan], [2, 15, 13, np.nan], [9, 14, np.nan, np.nan]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) 

df['count_nulls'] = len(df.columns) - df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
df['count_nonnull'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)-1
df['new_index'] = np.where(df['count_nonnull']==1, 1, 
                             np.where(df['count_nonnull']==0,0, df['count_nonnull'] - 1))
df['value'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df)), df['new_index']-1]
df
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for `notna` and do a reverse `cumsum` on `axis=1` , then get the first column that returns 2. and get its value using `df.lookup`:

```
u = df.notna().iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1)
df['value'] = df.lookup(df.index,u.eq(2).dot(u.columns+',').str.split(',').str[0])
```

---

```
print(df)

   a   b     c   d  value
0  1  10   NaN NaN      1
1  2  15  13.0 NaN     15
2  9  14   NaN NaN      9
```

Following comments since `lookup` is deprecated, one can use:

```
u = df.notna().iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1)
v = u.eq(2).dot(u.columns+',').str.split(',').str[0]
df['value'] = df.stack().loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((v.index,v))].to_numpy()
```

The other parts can be solved without resorting to apply, or the nested `np.where`

```
df.assign(
    count_nulls=df.isna().sum(1),
    count_non_null=df.notna().sum(1),
    new_index=lambda df: np.select(
        [df.count_non_null == 1, df.count_non_null == 0], 
         [1, 0], 
         df.count_non_null - 1))
```

Comment: i'm guessing this is not pandas version 1.2; lookup seems to have been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecations).

Comment: @Christopher didnt know about the deprecation, edited my answer.

Comment: no worries, @anky. Already gave my +1. If you dont mind, I'll add an extra solution to your answer for the other ones.

Comment: @sammywemmy absolutely , I wouldn't mind at all :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and access the second last element.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x:x.dropna().iloc[-2], axis=1)
0     1.0
1    15.0
2     9.0
```

Comment: doesn't work if you have more nulls in a row, or all nulls in one row

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(x.isnull().sum())[-2], axis = 1)
#0     1.0
#1    15.0
#2     9.0
```

The idea is to shift the rows "number of `NaN`s" times, so the second to last that is not `NaN` will be always in the second to last position.

Comment: this breaks down if you add more columns

Comment: @Christopher to the left or to the right? with nan values or without them?

Comment: @Christopher you can change `[2]` by `[-2]` to get the generalized case. I already edited it

Comment: the point is it needs to be dynamic. This doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Christopher i don't get it, can you give me an example where this doesn't work?